# Editing data grabbed from a recordset

Tags: html, asp-classic

Is it possible to edit data that is grabbed from a recordset? In my case, I am trying to add quantities together so that I can get a total. So an example of what I am trying to do would be:

```
<% 
   set rs = server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
   totalqty = 0

   do NOT while rs.EOF
       totalqty = totalqty + rs("QTY")
   loop
>%
```

Whenever I tried to do something like this, I would always get an 'Type MisMatch' Error and I'm not sure how to resolve this problem.

As always, any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to "cast" the value in the recordset like so:

```
CDbl( rs.fields("QTY").value )
```

This will cast the value to a double. If the value is null you will get en error so you have to check that first...

Or you can write a function to always get the correct type:

```vbs
public function parse(value, alternative)
    dim val
    val = trim(value & "")
    parse = alternative
    if val = "" then exit function
    on error resume next
    select case varType(parse)
        case 2, 3 'integer, long
            parse = cLng(val)
        case 4, 5 'single, double
            parse = cdbl(val)
        case 6  'currency
            parse = ccur(val)
        case 7 'date
            parse = cDate(val)
        case 11 'bool
            parse = cBool(val)
        case 8 'string
            parse = value & ""
        case else
            on error goto 0
            lib.throwError("type not supported. val:" & value & " alt:" & alternative)
    end select
    on error goto 0
end function

dim val : val = rs("QTY")
val = parse(val, 0)

' now val is always an integer (either the value from db or 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

ulluoink's solution will work, but this is simpler...

```
function ToDbl(vIn, nDefault)
    'Convert a variant to an integer using default where necessary
    if isnull(vIn) then
        ToDbl = nDefault
    else
        if IsNumeric(CStr(vIn)) Then
            ToDbl = CDbl(vIn)
        else
            ToDbl = nDefault
        end if
    end if
end function
```

Then just call:

```
totalqty = totalqty + ToDbl(rs("QTY"), 0)
```